# iOS - adding data from UIAlertView to sqlite

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite, ios7

I want to ask if user wants to add his score from game to highscores and in input I want to ask for his name. After he is done I have code like this:

```
ListOfScores *listOfScores =[[ListOfScores alloc] init];
        if ([listOfScores GetScoresCount] < 10) {
            [self ShowMessageBoxForHighScore];
        }
        else if([listOfScores GetLastScore] < self.ActualScore)
        {
            [self ShowMessageBoxForHighScore];
        }

- (void)ShowMessageBoxForHighScore
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"save score" message:@"input username:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    alert.tag = 12;

    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"save"];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 12) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            UITextField *textfield = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
            ListOfScores *listOfScores =[[ListOfScores alloc] init];
            Score* score = [[Score alloc] initWithName:textfield.text Points:self.ActualScore];
            [listOfScores AddScore:score];
        }
    }
}
```

These are my methods for checking and creating databases:

```
-(BOOL)CreateTableForScores {
    BOOL ret;
    int rc;
    // SQL to create new table

    NSString *sql_str = @"CREATE TABLE Scores (pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , Points INTEGER DEFAULT 0, Name VARCHAR(100))";

    const char *sqlStatement = (char *)[sql_str UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"query %s",sqlStatement);

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlStatement, -1, &stmt, NULL);

    ret = (rc == SQLITE_OK);
    if (ret)
    { // statement built, execute
        rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        ret = (rc == SQLITE_DONE);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt); // free statement
    NSLog(@"creating table");
    return ret;
}

-(BOOL)TableForScoresExists {
    sqlite3_stmt *statementChk;
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='Scores';", -1, &statementChk, nil);

    bool boo = FALSE;

    if (sqlite3_step(statementChk) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        boo = TRUE;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statementChk);

    return boo;
}
```

and my AddScore method:

```
- (void) AddScore:(Score *)newScore
{
    @try {
        BOOL tableExists = self.TableForScoresExists;
        if(!tableExists)
        {
            tableExists = self.CreateTableForScores;
        }

        if(tableExists)
        {
                NSString *filename = @"database.sqlite";
                NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                NSString *bundlePath       = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
                NSString *documentsFolder  = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
                NSString *documentsPath    = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
                //NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Milionar.sqlite"];
                const char *sql = "INSERT INTO Scores(Points,Name) VALUES(?,?)";


                if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath])
                {
                    BOOL success;
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:documentsPath error:&error];
                    NSAssert(success, @"Unable to copy database: %@", error);
                }

                if(sqlite3_open([documentsPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
                    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                    {
                        sqlite3_bind_int(sqlStatement, 1, newScore.Points); //
                        sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, 2, [newScore.Name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT); //

                        if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) != SQLITE_DONE)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                        }
                        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"An error has occured while opening database.");
                }

                sqlite3_close(db);

        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
    }

}
```

The problem is that in AddScore method I get false when I am trying to check if database exists. But when I don't use UIAlertView and I replace calling alert for AddScore with some text I get everything ok and I saved Score object. Where is the problem? Why it's not working in delegate method? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just to print textfield.text in that delegate method? Just to see if it's actually returning some string?

Comment: Yes, I have right data in there.

Comment: It looks like you are re-initializing `listOfScores` within `didDismissWithButtonIndex`?

Comment: I am not sure of the correct reason though, can you please try the DB related operations in another thread for e.g., using GCD approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both CreateTableForScores and TableForScoresExists require a working db pointer.

Thus you need to first open the db before calling any of these two properties.

In your current code snippet, both functions are potentially called with an uninitialized db pointer.

Also, you don't necessarily need to have a call to a method TableForScoresExists if you use "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " ( [https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html](https://www.sqlite.org/lang%5fcreatetable.html) ) 
That saves you some code.

Answer (score 1):

You must return a `BOOL` but you have a `bool`. In Obj-C they are not the same. Maybe fixing that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its the correct button index ? You call  `[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"save"];` later on in your code

Comment: Yes, when I have breakpoint I get in that method for add new score. `tableExists` is NO whole time (even after `self.CreateTableForScores` call).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `ShowMessageBoxForHighScore`, what if you just call this to test if this works:

```
ListOfScores *listOfScores =[[ListOfScores alloc] init];
Score* score = [[Score alloc] initWithName:@"TestName" Points:10];
[listOfScores AddScore:score];
```

That might help isolate the problem for you. My guess would be that it's probably got nothing to do with UIAlertView.

Comment: As I wrote in question. When I remove UIAlertView and call AddScore with some values everything is okay.